# How to undo applied subsurf?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I applied the subdivision modifier a while ago.
But Blender can't take it anymore I really need to undo it!
I already start over a bit with the project but I really do not feel like making the wings all over again and the hair....can someone help me?

Comment: CTRL+Z is your friend. Always test to check performance issues before applying, especially with the subdivision surface modifier, as it can really mess up your mesh. As far as directly UNDOING it, I don't know.

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/is-there-an-unsubdivide-function-in-blender

Comment: Never apply modifiers or convert curves to meshes unless strictly necessary, if you do make it as late as possible, and always keep a safe copy of the original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option that could help you to "undo" an applied subdivision surface modifier, although the best options are already said in comments (ie: a real undo before closing the file or keeping an unapplied copy of the object):

[image]

here is how it works on a simple cube

[image]