# Adding deactivated modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Is it possible to add a modifier that is not active? I mean, when having a few stacked modifiers already, adding e.g. a Bevel modifier, Blender always calculates for some seconds before that modifier is finally showing up.

Comment: You're asking if it's possible to add a object modifier with the activation checkbox unchecked? Like when you add a modifier, and toggle it to deactivate it, just automatically when you add it to an object?

Comment: No, not in the box. What are you doing that Blender need a **few** seconds for a modifier. Explain what you want and why it is that slow, someone may come up with a different solution.

Comment: Let's say you have a mesh with a Subdivision Modifier applied and realize you forgot a Bevel Modifier. Just adding it, this takes time, because the Bevel modifier now calculates geometry for every edge in the subdivided mesh. (I can turn off things, sure, but if adding deactivated modifiers is possible, learning that shortcut would be my preferred solution...)

Comment: imho if you apply a subdiv, you know that real and permanent geometry is added, and all subsequent actions/modifiers have to deal with it (maybe see this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86813/how-to-undo-applied-subsurf/86835#86835). If your bevel is added deactivated, how do you know it's working well?

Comment: Okay, sorry "applied" is the wrong word here. So, it should be "mesh with Subdivision Modifier already added and you realize..."

Comment: "If your bevel is added deactivated, how do you know it's working well?" This is not an extremely good argument because a lot of modifiers when being added need to be "configured" first. So, not seeing a result immediately when adding a modifier is happening most of the time...

Comment: Somewhat related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71569/how-to-add-modifiers-using-python-script-and-set-parameters. You can add modifier with script and write there modifier.show_viewport=False, but it will first add modifier and then set it visibility to false. Or you can add one object with such modifier hidden and link it to new object