# How to edit or hide modifiers in 2.8?

Tags: modifiers

Can I edit the modifiers applied to an object? https://ibb.co/9stPR5L There is a subsurface modifier applied to the orange part and I'd like to hide it to work on the shape better. After applying a modifier in 2.8, it "goes away" and I can't see it anymore. When I apply a new subsurface modifier to the object, it doesn't overwrite it, it adds it to the first one.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/is-there-an-unsubdivide-function-in-blender)

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a modifier to an object it becomes a part of the object and therefore vanishes from the modifier menu. The vertices of your object are changed permanently and you cannot reverse this step.

Because of that you will usually not apply modifiers, unless you really have to.

Comment: The Blender Guru managed to hide the subsurface modifier in a version before 2.8. And he managed to have the object shown with a smooth shape (with subsurf) AND have the basic grid shown and editable. He basically said that modifiers are put on top of an object so the two things, an object and its modifiers, can be edited seperately. These 2 pictures show what I mean in order: 1. Option for on or off: https://ibb.co/0hmtbqG   2. Basic grid WITH subsurf: https://ibb.co/30m5ByM

Comment: You can still do that in 2.8. Just don't push the "apply" button.
The "eye" symbol is now a small screen, but it is still in the same position.