# how to remove sub-surf modifier which has already been applied

Tags: modeling

I was making a hammer in Blender, after I applied a texture to it, it froze and I soon realised that I hadn't only applied the modifier but had also saved the Blender file. Now, is there a way to remove the modifier?

Thanks in advance to all those who can answer this.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Why not just recover autosave? *File > Recover > Autosave*. If that won't work, you can use the *Decimate modifier* set to *Un-Subdivide*.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/is-there-an-unsubdivide-function-in-blender

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an unsubdivide function in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/is-there-an-unsubdivide-function-in-blender)

Comment: You could consider using the "limited dissolve" function in edit mode.